# Mouse not working when I install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse

I install Ubuntu 22.04 on HP Elitebook 8570w but the mouse not working.
The mouse and keyboard are HID devices only, why do they can not work?
Note: The mouse not work while I install Ubuntu, not after installation.

Comment: I vote to keep this question open. I also have a HP EliteBook 8560w. Nether the mouse or track pad are working. I recall from when I built the computer that it used a lot of HP specific drivers.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvotes my question. I don't have time to joke around. Actually, I couldn't use any mouse while installing Ubuntu 20.04, the mouse was not damaged at all. Until now the problem has not been fixed.

Comment: here HP EliteBook 8270w on 21.10 mouse works fine, after upgrade to 22.04 mouse is dead. When I start 22.04 with the 5.13 kernel fron 21.10, the mouse is working. Sadly no clue how to fix it yet...

Comment: I installed 22.04 on my Dell laptop and this OS update is a piece of junk. Totally buggy. The mouse problem is just the tip of the iceberg.